# SQL Error 1054 Unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
SELECT id,                        
   (SELECT count(*) FROM log_like_authoriz, 
          (SELECT * FROM log_like_authoriz WHERE (user_id, id) in 
                    (SELECT user_id, MAX(id) FROM log_like_authoriz WHERE run_id = r.id GROUP BY user_id)
                  HAVING type_like <> 0) s WHERE t.id = s.id) AS like_count FROM run r ORDER BY id DESC
```

> Ошибка> 
>   SQL (1054): Unknown column 'r.id' in 'where clause'

как правильно определить это значение ID из таблицы RUN

---

```
SELECT count(*) FROM log_like_authoriz, 
          (SELECT * FROM log_like_authoriz WHERE (user_id, id) in 
                    (SELECT user_id, MAX(id) FROM log_like_authoriz WHERE run_id = 19 GROUP BY user_id)
                  HAVING type_like <> 0) s WHERE t.id = s.id
```

Этот запрос получает все лайки типа 1, для определенного run(например 19) по последней записи user_id (т.е. с максимальным id)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению к таблице из внешней части запроса можно обращаться только на первом уровне вложенности подзапроса. Единственный выход - как то переписать подзапрос так, что бы в нем не было больше вложенностей. Я по запросу не могу понять количество чего вы считаете и может ли оно быть больше 1 (там присутствует некая выборка по id, если id в этой таблице уникальны, то мне кажется, что больше 1 на выходе быть не может, а тогда запрос можно сильно упростить)

Comment: Как вариант, так как вы все равно получаете из run все записи, весь подзапрос перенести из списка выборки в часть from и получать там значения сразу для всех записей run, сгруппировав записи в подзапросе по run_id

Comment: Дописал, я просто над этим запросов всю ночь просидел, чтобы выбрать  лайки, даже не представляю как его переделать, он работает. Если к таблице из внешней части запроса можно обращаться только на первом уровне, то значит нужен вообще другой подход

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению таблица внутри запроса доступна только на первом уровне вложенности подзапросов. По этому запрос необходимо переделать таким образом, что бы не было необходимости ссылаться на внешнюю таблицу на глубоких уровнях.

Ваш запрос можно переделать как:

```
SELECT run_id as id, count(1)
  FROM (
    SELECT run_id, user_id
      FROM log_like_authoriz
     GROUP BY run_id, user_id
    HAVING MAX(id) = MAX( (type_like<>0) * id )
  ) x
 GROUP BY run_id
```

При необходимости дополнительных полей из таблицы run надо выполнить ее join к подзапросу "x".

Так как любая логическая операция (например `<>`) в MySQL дает в результате 0 или 1. То условие `(type_like<>0) * id` дает 0 в случае если type_like=0 или дает id при других type_like. Применяя к этому выражению MAX мы получаем максимальный id у которого не нулевой type_like. Если полученный id равен id последней записи для данного пользователя (в пределах run_id) - то это подходящая нам для подсчета запись.

Comment: Вроде бы работает, добавил WHERE run_id=run.id и убрал run_id as id, получилась одна цифра как надо для конкретного run. Но не подскажите что возвращает запрос если такого run_id нет, хорошо бы вернуть 0. Попытался добавить :

CASE
        WHEN count(1)=NULL
           THEN 0
        WHEN count(1)>0
           THEN count(1)
             END AS like_count

в первый SELECT, не отдает 0

Comment: IFNULL(count(1), 0) тоже не работает

Comment: @DenKapone Что бы вернуть NULL надо на что то "опереться", нельзя вернуть запись, которой нет. Вам надо написать `select r.id, count(x.user_id) FROM run r LEFT JOIN (подзапрос) x ON x.run_id=r.id`

Comment: Да, я понял, спасибо большое за помощь и потраченное на меня время ))

Comment: @DenKapone Да не за что :) А по поводу времени ... В следующий раз, пожалуйста, приводите пример данных в виде текста. Даже обычную табличку с разделителем пробел загнать в таблицу можно очень быстро. А вот перебивать с картинки строки для контрольного примера (я брал 19 run_id) несколько утомительно :)

Comment: Да понял, хорошо, я не подумал, вы бы сказали я бы сразу SQL дал с CREATE таблички и INSERT данных.